# Problem with stringify when sending array of objects to rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am sending an array of objects to my controller as

```
JSON.stringify(window.data)}
```

If one of the values in the json object has a space, the params will fail, showing it incomplete, for example if I input "a  a"

```
{"title": "aaa", "description":"a  a "}
```

in the params I will get:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "data"=>"[{\"title\":\"aaa\",\"description\":\"a",
 "locale"=>"en"}
```

The data is sent adding a hidden form before submission to a form_for:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(eventObj) {
    $(this).append(`<input type="hidden" name="data" value=${JSON.stringify(window.data)}>`);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Try gsubbing the string before you parse it `str.gsub(" ", "")` <- gsub space with no space.

Comment: Hi tblev , right now I am solving it with .replace in js (I replace spaces with "-") and then replacing those in ruby with spaces with gsub, but it feels like a "dirty" solution.

Comment: Hi mu is too short, I am adding a hidden field to my form_for before submission with the window.data object:

`
$('#my_form').submit(function(eventObj) {
    $(this).append(`<input type="hidden" name="data" value=${JSON.stringify(window.data)}>`);
    return true;
});

`